# What do you call that snorting noise/action people make when drawing phlegm to their mouth?

Tags: single-word-requests

It's done by narrowing or tightening the back of your tongue by pressing it to the roof of your mouth while forcefully "inhaling through your nose with your mouth closed" to draw in the phlegm. It has a snorting/snoring sound.

Edit: NOT hacking, or hocking or hawking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is *hawking*

> **hawk** [verb] (used without object)
>
> - to make an effort to raise phlegm from the throat; clear the throat noisily ...

[[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/hawking)]

(also used transitively)

....................

There are, of course, other homonyms.

Comment: Hawking (or hocking) is done with mouth open and usually there is no snorting vibrational sound

Comment: I have more often heard it (the relevant word I mean) as "hacking" or "hacking up", as illustrated by the open-mouth portions of this medley from Planes Trains and Automobiles: https://youtu.be/0t6_J97Bz-8&t=22s

Answer (score 0):

Closest thing I can think of is snorting mucus or as I've come across it others calling it sniffing mucus to spit it out. Prefer the first term more though since it matches the obnoxious sound people make doing it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).